# Python decrypt signatures with only a public key

Tags: python, encryption

A company wants to send me a **digital signature** i.e this [method](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Digital_signature). I only have the **public key**. This signature is used to authenticate who it came from **AND** contains details of the user, which I need.

What I don't understand is how I decrypt the signature with only public key and the signature I'm sent.  All can do from the example I can find is verify the signature. Without knowing what the encrypted string is you cannot decrypt.

```
from ecdsa import SigningKey, NIST384p
sk = SigningKey.generate(curve=NIST384p)
vk = sk.get_verifying_key()
signature = sk.sign("message")
assert vk.verify(signature, "message")
```

I'm I misunderstanding or is there a different type of digital signature they are suggesting?

Comment: Yes, you're misunderstanding. You don't decrypt signatures - only verify them.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure they are sending you only the signature? The idea behind digital signature is not to encrypt data, but to make sure the data actually came from the source it claims to be from. So, commonplace technique is to send both plain text message and it's digital signature, which is essentially the same message encryted with sender's private key.

Comment: @J0HN the "essentially the same message encrypted with sender's private key" applies only to RSA, and PKCS#1 v1.5 at that. Signatures don't work like that in DSA or ECDSA – you need a hash value in (EC)DSA to even tell if the signature is a correct signature, let alone check if it matches a public key.

Comment: @HubertKario I'm not a big expert in the cryptography (especially the elliptic-curve based), but after reading on tit a bit, I think I agree with you, but only partially, as your use of "hash" might be misleading. If I understood right, ECDSA-based digital signature consists of a pair of specially constructed values, generated from the hash of the message, the private key and some ~black magic~ elliptic-curve math. Those values aren't just a hash (even though they might look like one), and the hash itself is never passed to the other party.

Comment: @J0HN by "hash" I mean the number that you get by treating the actual hash as a big-endian integer. If you have just the public key and an ECDSA signature you won't be able to get the hash out of it, that would require solving the EC Discrete Logarithm Problem: the second value in the signature (`s`) has three unknowns: the `k` (the nonce), the hash value and the private multiplier, the one known value is the first parameter of the signature (`r`). So there's no way to derive the hash from just signature and public key.

Comment: @HubertKario Yes, but still, in the "digital signature" use case, the message is still passed in the plaintext, so the hash is redundant as it can be calculated from the message on the receiving side. it just requires using the same hash function (and parameters) on the receiving side, but it is a part of the protocol, not the message itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to use VerifyingKey.
(see also @J0HN excellent comment)
Something like (source: https://github.com/warner/python-ecdsa):

```
from ecdsa import VerifyingKey, BadSignatureError
vk = VerifyingKey.from_pem(open("public.pem").read())
message = open("message","rb").read()
sig = open("signature","rb").read()
try:
    vk.verify(sig, message)
    print "good signature"
except BadSignatureError:
    print "BAD SIGNATURE"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand now. So if my goal is data encryption would it be better for me to suggest standard symmetric key encryption where I give them a public key they create a sign from that and I used a private key to decrypt? If so, in Python is there a good standard lib for this ?

Comment: I strongly suggest you look at the definition of standard cryptographic terms (public key encryption, electronic signature, symmetric/asymmetric encryption) then post a question stating first the exact problem you want to solve, and second how you intend to solve it.